# javascript not working correctly when linked with file but working correctly when i paste the code in console

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>  
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <img src="imgs/1.jpg" id="img" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="imgs">
    <img src="imgs/1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/4.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/5.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/6.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/7.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/2.png" alt="">
    <img src="imgs/3.png" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>




var img = document.querySelector("#img");
img.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
 alert ("Hello World!");
}
```

this javascript file is linked correctly but not working apparently the error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**
but it works fine when i paste the code in console

Comment: Include the script at the end of the page.

Comment: Thank you Brother

Comment: You're welcome :)